# Not knowing how to translate a theorem to logic

Tags: logic-translation

Proposition: for every positive integer $n$, there do not exist four positive integers $a,b,c,d$ with $ad=bc$ and $n^2 <a<b<c<d<(n+1)^2$

I understand how to prove this by looking for a contradiction when assuming those integers exist. However, how do I translate this into a logic statement without using "$\nexists$"?

Comment: Hello. Are you aware that "$\nexists x,\, p(x)$" is equivalent to "$\forall x,\, \neg p(x)$"? (where $\neg$ means "not".) For instance, "There doesn't exist an animal who is a griffin" is equivalent to "Every animal that exists is not-a-griffin".

Comment: Great, thank you. This is what I initially thought but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stef provided the key idea in the comments, but let's do it in English.  First, for every positive integer $n$, whatever four positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ we select, the following statements cannot both be true:  $ad = bc$ and $n^2 < a < b < c < d < (n+1)^2$.  This phrasing is a bit awkward, however.  Saying "A and B cannot both be true" is the same as saying "if B is true, then A must be false".  Using this, we may rewrite the original proposition as follows:

For every positive integer $n$, if the positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ satisfy $n^2 < a < b < c < d < (n+1)^2$, then $ad \ne bc$.

I will leave it to you to translate these ideas expressed in English into ideas expressed in the notation of logic.